# MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch) El Capitan

Tags: macos, notifications

I have a Macbook Pro Retina 13 inch. 
I have recently lost my notifications in the notification centre. The "
today" tab functions but my "notifications" bar has nothing. The banners from notifications pop up but they are not saved in the "notifications" tab. I have attempted killing and restarting the notifications centre through Terminal but to no avail. Please help! TIA

Answer (score 1):

Check in your *System settings >> Notifications* on the left side on the Panel if **Do to disturbed** is in any way activated. Also check from which app you need Notifications and activate it.

Also you should look in the settings of *Security >> Privacy* if Notifications from your apps are disabled.